# How do i modify this to create a random array of a size i can input?

Tags: java, bubble-sort

```
class BubbleSort {
    void bubbleSort(int arr[]) {
        int n = arr.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
                if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                    // swap arr[j+1] and arr[i]
                    int temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                    arr[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void printArray(int arr[]) {
        int n = arr.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        BubbleSort ob = new BubbleSort();
        int arr[] = { 64, 34, 25, 12, 22, 11, 90 };
        ob.bubbleSort(arr);
        System.out.println("Sorted array");
        ob.printArray(arr);
    }
}
```

Would i have to make a separate array.util class and then another class to test it?
Also is it possible to print each iteration the bubble sort goes through.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String... args){
    // Get input size
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int size = scanner.nextInt();

    // Create Array based on size
    int[] testArray = new int[size];
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
        testArray[i] = (int)(Math.random()*size);
        Sysout.out.print(testArray[i]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();

    // Sort Array
    BubbleSort bs = new BubbleSort();
    bs.bubbleSort(testArray);
    bs.printArray(testArray);
}
```

And yes, u can output each step of the algorithm, just add print statement in the sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code instead of the array declaration line `int arr[] = {64, 34, 25, 12, 22, 11, 90};` to let a user enter the array size and then Java to generate random numbers and fill the array. Just replace the `int arr[] = {64, 34, 25, 12, 22, 11, 90};` line with the following code:

```
        Scanner inScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter array size: ");

        int arraySize = Integer.parseInt(inScanner.nextLine()); //Read the whole line and try to parse it into an Integer
        int start = 1;
        int end = 100;
        Random r = new Random();
        int arr[] = new int[arraySize];
        for (int i=0; i<arraySize; i++) {
            arr[i]= r.nextInt((end - start) + 1) + start;
        }
```

You can change the start/end integer to set different limits on the random number generator.

For testing the class you can use JUnit testing framework (Jmockit, mockito,etc).

To print each iteration of the bubblesort just add a System.out.println in the bubblesort method inside the `if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])` block.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of a given size filled up with random numbers from a given origin to a given upper bound in a method like this:

```
public static int[] createRandomNumbersArray(int size, int valMin, int valMax) {
    int[] arr = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        arr[i] = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(valMin, valMax);
    }

    return arr;
}
```

You would have to ask the user for the size (and maybe for the other values, too, but you can just define them yourself) and then invoke this method.